# Cannot upload changelog to TestFlight with fastlane

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-pilot

I'm trying to automate my TestFlight builds. It works great for the most part but when I include the changelog it claims that it **"Successfully set the changelog for build"** however I can't find the changelog text anywhere in AppStore Connect. It doesn't appear in TestFlight either.

Here's my lane:

```rb
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new dev build to TestFlight"
  lane :dev do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "MyApp.xcodeproj")
    build_app(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", scheme: "devMyApp")
    changelog = changelog_from_git_commits
    add_git_tag
    upload_to_testflight(
      app_identifier: "com.myApp.dev",
      changelog: changelog
    )
  end
end
```

When the lane gets executed I can see it successfully build, it pulls the git commit messages since the last tag, it uploads, waits for the app to appear, and it supposedly sets the changelog for the build. The changelog just doesn't appear anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is a known issue: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16129

Comment: Ahh great, loads of people with the problem and no solutions.

Comment: What worked for me is to use api_key instead of using `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 1):

In my case using both `changelog` and `localized_build_info` worked. Neither of them worked individually though.

```
   upload_to_testflight(      
      api_key: api_key,
      changelog: notes, 
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true, 
      localized_build_info: {
          "default": {
            whats_new: notes, 
          }
      }
    )
```